# SimpleOnPageListener not triggered

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have this class:

```
package com.shopkeep.pocketandroid.Utils;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.shopkeep.pocketandroid.PocketApplication;

public class PageChangeListener extends ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        Toast.makeText(PocketApplication.getContext(), "changed" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I'm using it here:

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getTabTitles(), getTabFragments());
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
SlidingTabLayout tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabs.setDistributeEvenly();

pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new PageChangeListener());
tabs.setViewPager(pager);
pager.setCurrentItem(getDefaultTabIndex());
```

I'm able to switch between tabs fine and the fragments load fine.

However, I'm not seeing my Toast and I've set a breakpoint in PageChangeListener and it's not getting triggered.

Why is this not being triggered? I want to be notified when the page changes.

I've tried implementing

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    Toast.makeText(PocketApplication.getContext(), "changed" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

too, no Toast.

Comment: Try extending ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener instead of SimpleOnPageChangeListener if you are interesting in onPageSelected.

Comment: Galvan, that's what SimpleOnPageChangeListener does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `setOnPageChangeListener` for `SlidingTabLayout` instead of viewpager.

Change `pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new PageChangeListener());`  to `tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(new PageChangeListener());`.

This is documented well in `SlidingTabLayout`

```
 /**
     * Set the {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using {@link SlidingTabLayout} you are
     * required to set any {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
     * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
     *
     * @see ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
     */
    public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
    }
```